# Is it possible to rewrite some query strings to HTTPS and keep everything else on HTTP?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, httpd.conf

I'm rewriting query strings to pretty URIs, example: `index.php?q=/en/contact` becomes `/en/contact` and all works nicely..

```
# httpd.conf

# HANDLE THE QUERY
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Is it even possible to rewrite single queries to force `https` and force everything else onto `http`? I've tried **many** different approaches that typically end in infinate loops. I could write a plugin to do this in PHP but figured it would be more effecient to handle this in the server conf. I'd be greatful for any advice.

**EDIT:**
To clarify, I'd like to be able to rewrite the non SSL `http://example.com/index.php?q=/en/contact` to the SSL enabled `https://example.com/en/contact` and every query that is not `/en/contact` get written to `http://example.com/...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

htaccess example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^en/contact$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule !^en/contact$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`http://domain/en/contact` redirect to `https://domain/en/contact` rewrite to index.php?q=en/contact

`http://domain/en/fo` rewrite to index.php?q=en/fo

`https://domain/en/fo` redirect to `http://domain/en/fo` rewrite to index.php?q=en/fo

`https://domain/en/contact` rewrite to index.php?q=en/contact

Comment: The preferred way to check for SSL is HTTPS variable ex. `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on`

Comment: Yes that works, but the issue still remains, all links followed from `https://domain.com/en/contact` remain on SSL, I need a way of forcing all other queries back to `HTTP` without getting stuck in an infinate loop.

Comment: I corrected the rules

Comment: That works really well, many thanks! Sorry I can't upvote yet (not enough rep)

Comment: This makes it a little more portable:  `RewriteRule ^(.*contact$|sign-in)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]`